# Alamofire and Digest-Auth

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4.2, digest-authentication

I am trying to implement in my Apps Digest-auth but i am struggling, or is not working properly.

I have setup my request as you describe in your `AuthenticationTestCase` and looks like the following code:

```
let userName = "***********"
let password = "***********"
let qop = "auth"
let xmlStr: String = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><methodCall><methodName>authenticate.login</methodName></methodCall>"
let postData:Data = xmlStr.data(using:  String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!
let url = URL(string: "https://app.**********.co.uk/service/mobile/digest-auth/\(qop)/\(userName)/\(password)")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true 
request.setValue("\(String(describing: xmlStr))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.setValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("IOS133928234892nil", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
request.setValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = postData 
     AF.request(request)
         .authenticate(username: userName, password: password)
         .response { response in ........
```

When I run the above code, I am receiving the following response from the remote server:

```
Response XML Error:
You must be authenticated to access this resource

Response Error Code: 401

Response Headers:
Optional([AnyHashable("X-Powered-By"): PHP/7.1.33, AnyHashable("Pragma"): no-cache, AnyHashable("Content-Length"): 310, AnyHashable("Date"): Fri, 22 May 2020 09:15:48 GMT, AnyHashable("Server"): Apache/2.4.41 () OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.1.33, AnyHashable("Cache-Control"): no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, AnyHashable("Content-Type"): Content-Type: application/xml, AnyHashable("Www-Authenticate"): Digest realm="Mobile",nonce="31JEmMdeSVfXWQ:OT/ndHY6ch/PjqFwA6uutg",opaque="c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14864c",qop="auth",algorithm="MD5", Digest realm="Mobile",nonce="31JEmMdeSVfXWQ:OT/ndHY6ch/PjqFwA6uutg",opaque="c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14864c",qop="auth",algorithm="SHA-512-256", Digest realm="Mobile",nonce="31JEmMdeSVfXWQ:OT/ndHY6ch/PjqFwA6uutg",opaque="c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14864c",qop="auth",algorithm="SHA-256", AnyHashable("Connection"): Keep-Alive, AnyHashable("Keep-Alive"): timeout=5, max=100, AnyHashable("Expires"): Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT])
```

> *Note:* If I do the same request via Postman, it works properly.
>   It looks like the Alamofire is not properly handling the Digest challenge.

Please could you help me on this issue?